# windows timing drift of performancecounter C++

Tags: c++, winapi, time, performancecounter

I am using *QueryPerformanceCounter*() function for measuring time in my application. This function also used in order to supply time line of my application life. Recently I have noticed that there is a drift of the time regarding other time-functions. Finally, I have written a small test to check whether the drift is real or not. (I use VS2013 compiler)

```
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <thread>
    #include <cstdio>

    static LARGE_INTEGER s_freq;

    using namespace std::chrono;

    inline double now_WinPerfCounter()
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER tt;
        if (TRUE != ::QueryPerformanceCounter(&tt))
        {
            printf("Error in QueryPerformanceCounter() - Err=%d\n", GetLastError());
            return -1.;
        }
        return (double)tt.QuadPart / s_freq.QuadPart;
    }

   inline double now_WinTick64()
   {
        return (double)GetTickCount64() / 1000.;
   }

   inline double now_WinFileTime()
   {
        FILETIME ft;
        ::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);

        long long * pVal = reinterpret_cast<long long *>(&ft);

        return (double)(*pVal) / 10000000. - 11644473600LL;
   }


    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        if (TRUE != ::QueryPerformanceFrequency(&s_freq))
        {
            printf("Error in QueryPerformanceFrequency() - Err=#d\n", GetLastError());
            return -1;
        }

        // save all timetags at the beginning
        double t1_0 = now_WinPerfCounter();
        double t2_0 = now_WinTick64();
        double t3_0 = now_WinFileTime();
        steady_clock::time_point t4_0 = steady_clock::now();

        for (int i = 0;; ++i)   // forever
        {
            double t1 = now_WinPerfCounter();
            double t2 = now_WinTick64();
            double t3 = now_WinFileTime();
            steady_clock::time_point t4 = steady_clock::now();

            printf("%03d\t %.3lf %.3lf %.3lf %.3lf \n",
            i,
            t1 - t1_0,
            t2 - t2_0,
            t3 - t3_0,
            duration_cast<nanoseconds>(t4 - t4_0).count() * 1.e-9
            );

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
        }
    return 0;
   }
```

The output was, confusing :

```
    000      0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
    ...
    001      10.001 10.000 10.002 10.002
    ...
    015      150.006 150.010 150.010 150.010
    ...
    024      240.009 240.007 240.015 240.015
    ...
    025      250.010 250.007 250.015 250.015
    ...
    026      260.010 260.007 260.016 260.016
    ...
    070      700.027 700.039 700.041 700.041
```

Why is there a difference ? It looks like one second duration is not same when using different API functions ? Also , during a day the difference is not constant ...

Comment: I've put some more information below. However, would you mind to tell the value of your **performance counter frequency (s_freq.QuadPart)**. This number would allow to give a deeper insight because it discloses information about your platform.

Comment: Hello @Arno, the s_freq.QuadPart equals 3507568

Comment: It would probably help to know what the timestamps are used for, since appropriate granularity will vary between applications. In a widely distributed environment, even variations in local gravity will eventually cause drift (although radio clocks and NTP can reset this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** The main reason for the drift you observe is an inaccuracy of the **performance counter frequency**. The system provides you with a constant value returned by `QueryPerformanceFrequency`. This constant frequency is only **near** the true frequency. It is accompanied by an **offset** and possible **drift**. Modern Platforms (Windows > 7, invariant TSC) have little offset and little drift.

Example: A 5 ppm offset would cause the time to move forward by 5 us/s or 432 ms/day faster than expected if you use the performance counter frequency to scale performance counter values to times.

**General:**
`QueryPerformanceCounter`and `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` are using different resources (hardware). Modern platforms derive `QueryPerformanceCounter` from the CPUs timestamp counter (TSC) and `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` uses PIT timer, ACPI PM timer, or HPET hardware. See [Intel 64® and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual, Volume 3B: System Programming Guide, Part 2](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3b-part-2-manual.pdf) for details.
It is unavoidable to deal with drift when the two APIs are using different hardware. However, you may extend your test code to calibrate the drift.
Frequency generating hardware is typically temperature sensitive. Therefore, the drift may vary, depending on the load. See
[The Windows Timestamp Project](http://windowstimestamp.com/description) for details.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal, affordable clocks never have infinite precision.  GetSystemTime() and GetTickCount() are periodically re-calibrated from an Internet time server, time.windows.com by default.  Which uses an unaffordable atomic clock to keep time.  Adjustments to catch up or slow down are gradual in order to avoid giving software a heart-attack.  The time they report will be off from the Earth's rotation by at most a few seconds, the periodic re-calibration limits long-term drift error.

But QPF is not calibrated, its resolution is far too high to allow these kind of adjustments to not affect the short interval measurements it is normally used for.  It is derived from a frequency source available on the chipset, picked by the system builder.  Subject to typical electronic part tolerances, temperature in particular affects accuracy and causes variable drift over longer periods.  QPF is therefore only suitable to measure relatively short intervals.

Inevitably both clocks can't be the same and you *will* see them drift apart.  You'll have to pick one or the other to be the "master" clock.  If long term accuracy is important then you'll have to pick the calibrated source, if high resolution but not accuracy is important then QPF.  If both are important then you need custom hardware, like a GPS clock.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, different functions measure time in different ways.

*QueryPerformanceCounter* - is a high-resolution time stamps or measure time    intervals.

*GetSystemTimeAsFileTime* - retrieves the current system date and time in UTC format.

So this is not quite correct to use this functions and compare time from them.

Comment: Well, I compare in millisec resolution. So I believe that 2 millisec drift during 10 sec is too much

Comment: That's not much, no, and the default system clock resolution in Windows is 15ms, so you are below that tolerance...

Comment: Well, in a couple of hours the drift is bigger than 1 sec, for my app it is not an option.

Comment: QueryPerformanceCounter was invented to reduce time offset. Other services use system time, but this func using own time measure.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bad idea to use multiple methods of the measurement; the different functions have different resolutions, you'll effectively be seeing noise from values getting rounded to their precision. And of course, a small amount of time will pass while setting t1..t4 as the functions take time to execute, so drift is unavoidable.

Comment: Well, I agree that it is a bad idea. That's exactly why I want to choose one method. I have used QPF, but when running for a whole day it had a drift of more than 1 sec. This is not an option in my application.

Comment: I also note you're using sleep in the loop - not sure if this is a dumbed-down example or how the real code executes - this could cause drift - events (or even interrupts if the application demands/supports it) would seem to be the way to go.

Comment: The sleep is only for this test. I has no real meaning. I just wanted to print once in a period (which should not be constant). The printed diff is regarding time=0.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime API. It is both high-precision and can adjust periodically from external time servers.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot assume that it s running on Win8 or higher OS